# Fscanf file read in matlab for mixed numeric and non-numeric data

Tags: matlab, file, file-io

I try to read data from file but I have no idea how to use fscanf normally.
Have file like this

```
surname1 A.A.(16 char everytime) 23323 3232 232322 ....

surname2 A.A. 23322 3232 232322 ....

surname3 A.A. 23322 3232 232322 ....
```

How to use fscanf here?

I do:

```
 fid=fopen( 'name.txt', 'rb' );
and variations of  S = fscanf(fid, '%16c,%s,%s,%s');
```

What should I write to have working program?

Comment: What format do you want the data in once it's read in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in data and the format of your text file stays always the same as you have shown, you can easily follows these two command line:

```
fid = importdata('yourfile.txt');
res = fid.data;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If my answer is what you were looking for, you may up vote it and accept as the desired answer.

Comment: I cant vote, I have 1 point here(
When I ll have 15+ I will!)

Comment: @Antonina: but you can accept the answer I guess (if you find it useful of course).